# How can I solve for x with Ax=B, when A and X are 1-d arrays and I know A?

Tags: python, performance, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, inverse

In my original code I have the following function:

```
B = np.inner(A,x)
```

where `A.shape` = [307_200] and has values -1 or 1

where `x.shape` = [307_200] and has values 0 to 256

where B results in a integer with a large value.

**Assuming I know A and B, but don't know x, how can I solve for x??**

To simplify the problem...

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.choice(a=[-1,1], size=10)
x = np.random.choice(a=range(0,256), size=10)
B = np.inner(A, x)
```

I want to solve for x now. So something like one of the following...

```
x_solved = np.linalg.solve(A,x)
x_solved = np.linalg.lstsq(A,x)
```

### Is it possible?

Extra info...

I could change A to be a n x m matrix, but since I am dealing with large matrices, when I try to use `lstsq` I quickly run out of memory. This is bad because 1. I can't run on my local machine and 2. the end use application needs to limit RAM.

However, for the problem above, I can except RAM intensive solutions since I might be able to moderate the compute resources with some cleaver tricks.

Also, we could switch A to boolean values if that would help.

Apologies if solution is obvious or simple.

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Are you looking for a unique solution, or just _a_ solution?

Comment: Any solution that minimizes the difference between x_solved and x. Some difference is acceptable, but not preferred.

Comment: Try a genetic algorithm or solve directly by Newton-Raphson method if f(x) includes floating-point variables / has derivative and A/B are 2D matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem re-stated:

> I have an array `A` containing many 1s and -1s. I want to make another array `x` containing integers 0-255 so that when I multiply each entry by the corresponding first array, then add up all the entries, I get some target number `B`.

Notice that the problem is just as difficult if you shuffle the array elements. So let's shuffle them so all the 1s are at the start and all the -1s are at the end. After solving this simplified version of the problem, we can shuffle them back.

Now the simplified problem is this:

> I have `A1` number of 1s and `A-1` number of -1s. I want to make two arrays `x1` and `x-1` containing numbers from 0-255 so that when I add all the numbers in `x1` and subtract all the numbers in `x-1` I get some target number `B`.

Can you work out how to solve this?

I'd start by filling `x1` with numbers 255 until the next 255 would make the sum too high, then fill the next entry with the number that makes the sum equal the target, then fill the rest with 0s. Then fill `x-1` with 0s. If the target number is negative, do the opposite. Then un-shuffle it - match up the `x1` and `x-1` arrays with positions of the the 1s and -1s in your array `A`. And you're done.

You can actually write that algorithm so it puts the numbers directly in `x` without needing to make the temporary arrays `x1` and `x-1`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is a solution, but does not try to recover the original x value. There is much difference between x_recovered and x.

Comment: @Yume Well I told you what the problem is equivalent to. Can you see why it is impossible to recover the original X value?

Comment: Yes, I see how there is a set of answers but I don’t see why it’s impossible to find the right one. Im going to try a GA.

Comment: @Yume It's impossible because how can you tell which one is the right one? There could be zillions of answers that all work. How do you pick the right one?